# How to add to a js array after ajax form submit and have the displayed array display the new value without the page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ajax

I have a form to create a new item in the db, it does this through ajax. I also have an array on the page displaying all the current items. When I add  a new item using ajax i want the items list to update and add the new item.

I'm using ruby on rails with the gon gem to make the js array so the js array isn't getting the values from the db its getting them from the rails array which is getting it from the db. If I update the js array on form submit it will still grab it from the rails array that hasn't been updated.

I figured to just have the submitted string value to be added to the array after it is saved to the db. And then have the array updated on the page without the page re loading.

My main problem is how to grab the submitted string adding it to the array and once it is added to the array, how to update the array on the page.

here is the ajax coding

```
var key_name = gon.keys
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#new_category_item_key').submit(function(event) {
  if ($(this).find('.required[value=""]').length == 0) {
    alert('Please submit a name!');
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $('#new_category_item_key').attr('action'),
      data: string
    }).success(function(json) {
  key_name.push( '??' ); // do I just do push.(this)?
      // what to do to call for the displayed looped array to be updated
      alert('New key added');
    });
  }
 });

});
```

Here is the loop displaying the keys from the js array

```
<script>
  for (i=0;i<key_name.length;i++)
{
    document.write(key_name[i] + " | ");
}
  end
</script>
```

The array is just a standard array ["keyname1", "keyname2", "keyname3"]

I'm still learning JQuery ajax and js. This is something I don't know how to do.

**Update**
using this to try and get the array updated and to refresh the atray displayed

```
   }).success(function(json) {
    key_name.push(json);
      $("#keys_list").load(location.href + " #keys_list");
      alert('New key added');
    });
```

the div around the loop through the array

```
<div id="keys_list">
 <script>
  for (i=0;i<key_name.length;i++) {
   document.write(key_name[i] + " | ");
   }
  end
 </script>
</div>
```

This runs `alert('Please submit a name!');` even if there is a value submitted, it also saves the data but doesn't update the div so the array is updated.

Comment: What you should be pushing to `key_name` is not `this`, but something in your `json` response object. It would be helpful if you were to show us the value of `json`.

Comment: What do you mean by the value of json?

Comment: After you push the response onto `key_name`, you need to call whatever function you have that updates the DOM to display all the data in `key_name`.

Comment: @user3234020 You have a `function(json) {...}`. `json` is the response from the server.

Comment: So `key_name.push(json)`

Comment: Not necessarily. You need to know what value is `json`. Try `console.log(json);` and watch your console.

Comment: I cant get it to work it gets to `if ($(this).find('.required[value=""]').length == 0) {
    alert('Please submit a name!');` and gives the alert